# What's the substitue of MSE in GAMs?

Tags: logistic, binary-data, generalized-additive-model, mse, mgcv

In case a linear regression, Mean Square Error (MSE) is defined as:

$$
\frac{1}{n-k-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(y_i-\hat{y}_i)^2},
$$

where $n$ is the number of observations, $k$ is the number of independent variables, $y_i$ and $\hat{y}_i$ are the $i$th observed value of the response variable and its prediction, respectively.

Now what is the equivalence of MSE in a generalized additive model (GAM)? Especially in case of a binary GAM (which means a binary response variable)?

Edit: Please provide the corresponding option of your answer in package mgcv.

Comment: If your question was answered to your satisfaction, you can accept an answer by clicking on the check mark under the voting arrows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, the model deviance or the Pearson statistic are substituted for RSS. As the latter can under-smooth heavily, deviance-based variants are preferred (Wood, 2017, p 261).

The unbiased risk estimator (UBRE) is one way to estimate MSE in GAMs with know scale parameter $\phi$. In the binary GAM UBRE would be (using the notation of Wood, 2017)

$$\mathcal{V}_a(\boldsymbol{\lambda}) = D(\hat{\beta}) + 2 \gamma \phi \tau$$

where $D(\hat{\beta})$ is the deviance of the model at the parameter estimates, $\tau$ is the model effective degrees of freedom, $\gamma$ is usually 1 but can be used to put an additional penalty on degrees of freedom (1.4 is commonly used in the smoothing literature, and 1.5 has special justification from the view point of *double cross validation*), $\phi \equiv 1$ from the binomial distribution, and $\boldsymbol{\lambda}$ is the vector of smoothing parameters. Hence $\mathcal{V}_a(\boldsymbol{\lambda})$ is the UBRE at the current values of the smoothness parameters.

The $D(\hat{\beta})$ component replaces the $\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2$ part of your equation.

If $\phi$ is not known but rather estimated instead, then generalised cross validation (GCV) can be used in place of UBRE. The corresponding GCV score is defined as:

$$\mathcal{V}_g(\boldsymbol{\lambda}) = nD(\hat{\beta}) / (n - \gamma \tau)^2$$

where $n$ is the number of observations.

If using **mgcv** in R, then the above are automatically used for smoothness selection via the default option `method = "GCV.Cp"`. This criterion automatically selects between UBRE and GCV depending on whether the `family` implies a known, fixed value of $\phi$ or whether this is estimated from the data.

Alternative approaches are available:

- `method = "GACV.Cp"` uses a related measure *generalised approximate cross validation*
- `method = "ML"` and `method = "REML"` treat the smoothing problem as a mixed effects problem and estimate models and perform smoothness selection by maximising the likelihood or restricted likelihood of the model after converting the smooths into fixed and random effect terms.
- others; see `?gam` and argument `method`.

Wood, S. N. (2017) *Generalized Additive Models: An Introduction with R*. Second Edition. (Chapman and Hall/CRC).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. So totally speaking, I can use GCV score as MSE? If yes, it does not depend on `method` I think. For example, I can set `method="REML"`, and then extract the GCV score and use it as MSE?

Comment: The GCV score is not MSE, but it is an estimator of MSE. What is stored in `model$gcv.ubre` depends on `method`. If you use `method = "REML"` then it contains the REML score of the model. Same for the other methods. Only with `method = "GCV.Cp"` does `model$gcv.ubre` contain GCV score (unknown $\phi$) or UBRE score (known $\phi$). Note you can't fit the model twice one with `method = "REML"` and then again with the default method just to get the GCV score of the REML-fitted method. You would need to compute the GCV score from the fitted REML model.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of MSE is not the usual one. Compared to the usual one, it adds $-k-1$ to the divisor. Notice that because your definition divides by something other than just $n$, it isn't actually a mean.

At any rate, MSE, as a measure of fit (or a measure of predictive accuracy, if you calculate errors for values on which the model hasn't currently been trained, as in cross-validation), is model-neutral. It works just as well for GAMs as for linear regression. MSE is also helpful for the case of probabilistic classification, in which case it is a [proper scoring rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_scoring_rule) and is also known as the Brier score. For ordinary (non-probabilistic) classification, there are many other metrics, such as zero-one loss.

Comment: Using MSE for GAMs as in ordinary regression is a good idea. But there is an issue with binary GAMs: In a binary GAM the predictions are given for probabilities, $\hat{p}_i$'s, which replace $\hat{y}_i$'s in MSE formula. But what should replace $y_i$'s?

Comment: @M.Er 1 for when the event occurred and 0 when it didn't. That's how the Brier score works.

Comment: I got the idea with Brier score. But how about if I want to use logits of predictions? Logit of $\hat{p}_i$ is $log(\hat{p}_i/(1-\hat{p}_i))$, but 0 and 1 can not be used in a logit function as in case of Brier score. Is there a similar formula for logits?

Comment: @M.Er To use Brier score in the context of logistic regression, you transform the logits of the predicted probabilities back to probabilities first. Then you can look at the squared differences between the probabilities and 0-or-1 outcomes.